# Obx ListView not updating after value changes

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am having a `RxList` called `todoData`. On the basis of this list, a `ListView.builder` builds a list and in each list there is a button. When this button is clicked the `done` field of the respective item is updated to either `true` or `false`. But, though the value is updated the ui is no changing.
Here's the list:

```
class StateController extends GetxController {
  RxList<Todo> todoData = <Todo>[
Todo(
    name: 'todo1',
    done: true),
Todo(
    name: 'todo2',
    done: false),
Todo(
    name: 'todo3',
    done: true),
Todo(
    name: 'todo4',
    done: false),
Todo(
    name: 'todo5',
    done: false)
 ].obs;
}
```

Controller:

```
  final StateController _controller = Get.find();
```

The update function:

```
void updateItem(Todo e) {
  /* final int index = _controller.todoData.indexOf(e);
  _controller.todoData[index].done = !e.done; */
  _controller.todoData.firstWhere((Todo i) => i == e).done = !e.done;
  _controller.refresh();
}

void deleteItem(Todo e) {     //**this works**
  final int index = _controller.todoData.indexOf(e);
  _controller.todoData.removeAt(index);
}
```

Ui:

```
Obx(() => ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: _controller.todoData.length,
                          itemBuilder: (_, int i) => TodoItem(
                              item: _controller.todoData[i],
                              updateItem: () =>
                                  updateItem(_controller.todoData[i]),
                        ))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: try get builder then update() obx sometime using update kind a messy wont do anything unless add or delete or view

Comment: where your done button that call updateItem?

Answer (score 7):

`Obx` only reacts to changes made in reactive (Rx) variables. The only reactive variable you have currently is the `RxList`, so only changes made to that list will trigger your `Obx` to update.

When you change `done`, you're changing a value in `Todo`, not the list, so no update is made to the UI.

One way to fix this is to force an update in the list when you change `done`, you can do this by calling `refresh()` on the `RxList`:

```dart
void updateItem(Todo e) {
  _controller.todoData.firstWhere((Todo i) => i == e).done = !e.done;
  _controller.todoData.refresh(); // <- Here
}
```

(Also, assuming `e` is the same object contained in the list, you can do `e.done = !e.done` directly)

Answer (score 3):

i just modify some code of yours, just change the RxList to simple List and bool variable to RxBool and use obx on bool I'm sharing code

Your Model class and controller class

```
    class StateController extends GetxController {
      List<Todo> todoData = <Todo>[
        Todo(name: 'todo1', done: true.obs),
        Todo(name: 'todo2', done: false.obs),
        Todo(name: 'todo3', done: true.obs),
        Todo(name: 'todo4', done: false.obs),
        Todo(name: 'todo5', done: false.obs)
      ].obs;
    }
    
    class Todo {
      String? name;
      RxBool? done;
      Todo({this.name, this.done});
    }
```

your UI Code

```
    class TestClass extends StatelessWidget {
      TestClass({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
      final StateController _controller = Get.put(StateController());
    
      void updateItem(Todo e) {
        /* final int index = _controller.todoData.indexOf(e);
      _controller.todoData[index].done = !e.done; */
        _controller.todoData.firstWhere((Todo i) => i == e).done!.value =
            !e.done!.value;
        _controller.refresh();
      }
    
      void deleteItem(Todo e) {
        //**this works**
        final int index = _controller.todoData.indexOf(e);
        _controller.todoData.removeAt(index);
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            body: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _controller.todoData.length,
                itemBuilder: (_, int i) => TodoItem(
                      item: _controller.todoData[i],
                      updateItem: () => updateItem(_controller.todoData[i]),
                    )));
      }
    }
    
    class TodoItem extends StatelessWidget {
      TodoItem({Key? key, this.item, this.updateItem}) : super(key: key);
      Todo? item;
      VoidCallback? updateItem;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(
            item!.name!,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          subtitle: GestureDetector(
            onTap: updateItem,
            child: Obx(() {
              return Text(
                item!.done!.value.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              );
            }),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can do here to make your code work as expected.

First, you need to make sure that your Todo class implements the Equatable mixin. This will allow you to compare two Todo instances by value rather than by reference.

Second, you need to use the update() method on your RxList to update the value of the done field for the appropriate Todo instance.

Third, you need to call the refresh() method on your StateController after updating the done field so that the UI will be updated to reflect the new value.

Fourth, you should consider using the TodoItem widget's built-in updateItem() method rather than passing a callback to the widget. This will ensure that the TodoItem widget is updated correctly when the done field is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Try Calling the Update Function inside

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
            // Update Code Goes Here //
 });
```

The update may not happen when Obx is already In process of Building. The [addPostFrameCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html) will execute after the current build has finished and it will allow the UI to be updated.